# FATAL: role "root" does not exist error in Patroni Helm Chart while creating db schema automatically through Helm Chart

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes-helm, high-availability, patroni

I am using [patroni](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/patroni) helm chart. There is no facility to create schema automatically. So I provided a ConfigMap as below:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: {{ template "patroni.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "patroni.fullname" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
data:
  init.sql: |-
    **DB SCHEMA TO BE CREATED**
```

And in Kind Statefulset, in volumeMounts section I provided mountPath as below to mount the init.sql file in container. So the init.sql file gets mounted to /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql

```
volumeMounts:        
        - mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/     
          name: test
```

And in volume section I added below lines

```
volumes:
      - name: test
        configMap:
          name: {{ template "patroni.fullname" . }}
```

So, when I deploy the chart, it is deployed with no error.
When I exec into the pod, I can see the init.sql file which I have provided in the ConfigMap.
But that script is not executed, when I try running it manually through command

*psql -f init.sql*

I get error as psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist

The commands I executed are:

***oc exec -it postgres-ha-test-patroni-0 bash***

This container is managed by supervisord, when stopping/starting services use supervisorctl

Examples:

supervisorctl stop cron supervisorctl restart patroni

Current status: (supervisorctl status)

cron                             RUNNING   pid 31, uptime 0:45:42 patroni                          RUNNING   pid 32, uptime 0:45:42 pgq  RUNNING   pid 33, uptime 0:45:42

**root@postgres-ha-test-patroni-0:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d# *psql -f docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql***

psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist

Here, root role does not exist. If I login through postgres user and execute .sql file, it runs properly.
But I want to run it automatically, once I deploy patroni helm chart, the db schema should also be created.

Please help me with it. I am trying from long time.